Rearrange the columns in Google Sheet
Please help me with refilling the blank rows so that the next row takes the position of the empty row.
In the image below row "27" is empty up to column "I", I want to adjust it so that the data on row 28 with all other rows goes upward and fills up row 27.


I think you mixed the word row and column. Row is horizontal, column is vertical. But I have still no clue what you'd like to achieve anyway, sorry.

I want rows to move upward to fill up the space on empty row.

Can you share the expected result? Do you want the columns A to I to move but the column J will stay? For example on row 28(A-I) it will all go up so it will be aligned to the data Bournemouth?
Also please share a copy of your spreadsheet so we can replicate easier

Suggestions:
You can just use a simple QUERY() to remove the empty cells.
=QUERY(Sheet1!A:J,"Select * where A is not NULL")

Sample Data:

Result Using Query:

2nd Suggestion:
From your posted answer if you will just sort according to Column A you did not need to use another column. You can just Apply a filter to your data and sort directly to Column A, or you can filter to remove the blanks.


First, create an extra column on the right side of the data. Then put the formula =IF(A1<>"", 1, 0). Drag and formula to all the rows. After that, select the sheet and navigate to Data > Sort Range > Sort Range by column A (A to Z)
